# Improving a landau-gaussian convoluted fit using ROOT

Tags: distributions, fitting

I am using the landau-gaussian convolution fit (available here - https://root.cern.ch/root/html/tutorials/fit/langaus.C.html) for my data but I fail to understand the behaviour of the fits. For some chips, it is closer to expectation (figure 1) while for some it is totally off (figure 2). Also, I noticed that the fit somehow worsens drastically when I have more data (comparing figures 1 and 2 with figure 3). I am probably not very good with the concepts of fitting, especially with those of a convoluted landau-gaussian fit and therefore, not able to figure out the reason behind this. I don’t know what I should do in order to improve the fit. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated! :)

The code and figures are hereunder:

```
#include "../inc/myheaderfile.h"
#include "mylangaus.C"
#include "TPaveStats.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    ifstream histFile;
    histFile.open("histolist_new.txt");
    string histName;

    int count = 0;
    string inFileName = argv[1];
    TFile *inFile = new TFile(inFileName.c_str());
    TFile *outFile = new TFile("langaufit.root", "RECREATE");

    while(getline(histFile,histName) && count < 3){     // accessing only first 3 histnames for debug run
    //while(getline(histFile,histName)){                // accessing all histnames for analysis run

        string histName0 = histName + "_0";
        string histName1 = histName + "_1";
        TH1D *hist0 = (TH1D*)inFile->Get(histName0.c_str());
        TH1D *hist1 = (TH1D*)inFile->Get(histName1.c_str());
        if(hist0->GetEntries() == 0 || hist1->GetEntries() == 0) continue;

        /*
        The Landau * Gaussian parameters:
          par[0]=Width (scale) parameter of Landau density
          par[1]=Most Probable (MP, location) parameter of Landau density
          par[2]=Total area (integral -inf to inf, normalization constant)
          par[3]=Width (sigma) of convoluted Gaussian function

        Variables for langaufit call:
          his             histogram to fit
          fitrange[2]     lo and hi boundaries of fit range
          startvalues[4]  reasonable start values for the fit
          parlimitslo[4]  lower parameter limits
          parlimitshi[4]  upper parameter limits
          fitparams[4]    returns the final fit parameters
          fiterrors[4]    returns the final fit errors
          ChiSqr          returns the chi square
          NDF             returns ndf
        */

        /* --------- Hist0 Fit --------- */

        // Setting fit range and start values
        double fr0[2], sv0[4], pllo0[4], plhi0[4];
        fr0[0] = 0.;         fr0[1] = 200.;
        sv0[0] = 1.;         sv0[1] = 55.;        sv0[2] = 50000.0;        sv0[3] = 5.;
        pllo0[0] = 0.5;      pllo0[1] = 45.;      pllo0[2] = 1.0;          pllo0[3] = 1.;
        plhi0[0] = 3.;       plhi0[1] = 65.;      plhi0[2] = 100000.0;     plhi0[3] = 10.;

        // Return values
        double fp0[4], fpe0[4];
        double chisqr0;
        int ndf0;
        TF1 *fitVAEnergy0 = langaufit(hist0,fr0,sv0,pllo0,plhi0,fp0,fpe0,&chisqr0,&ndf0);

        double Peak0, FWHM0;
        langaupro(fp0,Peak0,FWHM0);

        /* --------- Hist1 Fit --------- */

        // Setting fit range and start values
        double fr1[2], sv1[4], pllo1[4], plhi1[4];
        fr1[0] = 0.;         fr1[1] = 200.;
        sv1[0] = 3.;         sv1[1] = 40.;        sv1[2] = 50000.0;        sv1[3] = 5.;
        pllo1[0] = 0.5;      pllo1[1] = 30.;      pllo1[2] = 1.0;          pllo1[3] = 1.;
        plhi1[0] = 5.;       plhi1[1] = 50.;      plhi1[2] = 100000.0;     plhi1[3] = 10.;

        // Return values
        double fp1[4], fpe1[4];
        double chisqr1;
        int ndf1;
        TF1 *fitVAEnergy1 = langaufit(hist1,fr1,sv1,pllo1,plhi1,fp1,fpe1,&chisqr1,&ndf1); // https://root.cern.ch/root/html/tutorials/fit/langaus.C.html

        double Peak1, FWHM1;
        langaupro(fp1,Peak1,FWHM1); // https://root.cern.ch/root/html/tutorials/fit/langaus.C.html

        /* --------- Print & Save --------- */

        TCanvas *c1 = new TCanvas("c1",histName.c_str(),800,600);

        // Global style settings
        gStyle->SetOptStat(1111);
        gStyle->SetOptFit(111);
        gStyle->SetLabelSize(0.03,"x");
        gStyle->SetLabelSize(0.03,"y");

        hist0->SetTitle(histName.c_str()); 
        hist0->SetMaximum((hist0->GetMaximum())*1.1);

        hist0->Draw("hist");
        fitVAEnergy0->SetLineColor(kRed);
        fitVAEnergy0->Draw("hist same");

        hist1->Draw("hist sames");
        fitVAEnergy1->SetLineColor(kBlue);
        fitVAEnergy1->Draw("hist sames");

        gPad->Update();
        TPaveStats* sb0=(TPaveStats*)hist0->FindObject("stats");
        sb0->SetX1NDC(.65);
        sb0->SetX2NDC(.85);
        sb0->SetY1NDC(.65);
        sb0->SetY2NDC(.85);
        sb0->SetTextColor(kRed);
        TPaveStats* sb1=(TPaveStats*)hist1->FindObject("stats");
        sb1->SetX1NDC(.65);
        sb1->SetX2NDC(.85);
        sb1->SetY1NDC(.4);
        sb1->SetY2NDC(.6);
        sb1->SetTextColor(kBlue);
        c1->Print();

        outFile->WriteTObject(c1);
        delete c1;
        count++;
        cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;

    } // end of while loop over all VA histograms 

    outFile->cd();
    outFile->Write();
    outFile->Close();
    return 0;
} // end of main
```

[image]

Comment: Are you able to use other statistical distributions, or does your work mostly require only this one?